# In App Purchase setup for a rejected app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

My app was rejected as l needed to use in app purchase for a feature, but l cant seem to get a list of products.

Everything is setup just does not return list of products. Does anyone have a list of steps l need to do as l am sure its around the setup of the app, certificates etc and not the code

Will also consider paying for feature if need be as well need it asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "everything is setup" what do you mean? What do you get in your `SKProductsRequestDelegate`? It gives you a `SKProductsResponse` which has two properties: `products` which gives you a list of valid products and `invalidProductIdentifiers` which lists those that you can't use.

There is a lot of documentation on this. Apple provides a Step-by-Step Guide in the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW2). Other resources that I've found useful are this "[Brain Dump](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/?p=856)" and [this thread in the Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/23344?tstart=45).